# Recursively find points with a grid-aligned tangent on spline

Tags: python, bezier

I am trying to find the points on a spline where the tangent is perfectly vertical or horizontal, using python and svgpathtools

An approach solving the equations isn't giving good results, so I am attacking the problem by approximation.

Right now my approach is as follows:

```
def approx_flex_points_recursive(spline, start=0, end=1, precision=10000):
    number_of_steps = precision
    step = 1 / (number_of_steps - 1)
    p = start
    e = 10 / number_of_steps

    relevant_points = []

    while p <= end:
        unit = path.unit_tangent(p)

        if (abs(unit.real) < e) or (abs(unit.imag) < e):
            relevant_points.append([ p, unit.real, unit.imag])
        p += step    
    return relevant_points
```

Which - for a high enough precision - gives me good points. I'd like to improve this by recursively look for good enough points and then iterate with higher precision in their surroundings.

Before I go through the trouble of hand-rolling all that, I was wondering: is there something that provides a battle tested approach to this? I was poking around scikit optimization but would be grateful for anything that helps narrow the search and set me on the right way.

Comment: Are you asking about inflection points (e.g. where the curvature switches sign), or specifically points where the tangent is aligned to the grid by either having a zero x or y component? Because those are two rather different problems, with different answers.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans aligned to the grid. Honored to meet you, sir

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as finding grid-aligned tangents, think of it as solving for the mathematical identity: you want all points for which the derivative is zero (when the x derivative is zero, that's a vertical tangent, and when the y derivative is zero, that's a horizontal tangent), also know as root finding. Scipy has [quite a few options](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) for that so  you'll probably want to do a bit of (re)searching on which of the many options is best suited to your particular use case.